# ironpython installation problem

Tags: ironpython, .net-3.0

.net 3.0 is installed, but ironpython is still showing 
'.net 2.0 sp1 is required or later'

Answer (score 1):

.NET 3.0 does not include .NET 2.0SP1. (.NET 2.0 SP1 was released along with .NET 3.5 SP0.) It's probably easiest to just get .NET 3.5 SP1 which is the latest fully-released version.

Alternatively, you could get [.NET 3.0 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=EC2CA85D-B255-4425-9E65-1E88A0BDB72A&displaylang=en) which includes .NET 2.0 SP1.